# Php,perform the operation in php,one of interviewer asked me, the same

Tags: php

Display the elements which has 5 on the right side(right most).

```
Input :{55,4,121,3333,65}
Output:{55,65}
```

2)display all the elements which has 2 digits in the first position and rest as it is.

```
Input:{122,3333,44,77777,9,13,5555}
Output:{44,13,122,3333,77777,9,5555}.
```

Please help me out. try to give answer in php.

Comment: I hope you didn't get the job because you're not really a programmer.

Comment: I agree with both of those comments. The only reason I gave an answer is because I was bored and missed getting problems like this in school :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something fun I would have to do in school. Here's the code fresh off the press!

Working demo (until I remove it): http://blazerunner44.me/test/fun.php

**Question 1:**

```
function question1($input){
    $result = array();
    foreach($input as $number){
        $numberString = (string)$number;
        $lastNumber = (int)substr($numberString, -1);
        if($lastNumber == 5){
            array_push($result, $number);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$answer1 = json_encode(question1(array(55,4,121,3333,65)));
echo($answer1);
```

**Question 2:**

```
function question2($input){
    $result = array();
    foreach($input as $number){
        $numberString = (string)$number;
        if(strlen($numberString) >= 2){
            array_push($result, $number);
        }
        elseif($numberString[0] == $numberString[1]){
            array_push($result, $number);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$answer2 = json_encode(question2(array(122,3333,44,77777,9,13,5555)));
echo($answer2);
```

Since your question wasn't very specific, let me know if you need me to explain how something works.